# Does Integer.valueOf() in java translate to int.Parse() in C#?

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to learn java from a C# background! I have found some nuances during my journey like C# doesn't have an Integer as reference type it only has int as a primitive type; this lead me to a doubt if this translation would be correct!

```
  String line ="Numeric string";//Java
  string line = "Numeric string";//C#
  int size;

  size = Integer.valueOf(line, 16).intValue(); //In Java

  size = int.Parse(line,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);//In C#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not quite a valid translation - because the 16 in the Java code means it should be parsed as an integer. The Java code is closer to:

```
int size = Convert.ToInt32(line, 16);
```

That [overload of `Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) allows you to specify the base.

Alternatively you could use:

```
int size = int.Parse("11", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

I'm not keen on the name "allow hex specifier" as it suggests that a prefix of "0x" will be accepted... but in reality it means it's *always* interpreted as hex.

Answer (score 1):

In java, this is better:

```
Integer.parseInt(line, 16);
```

it parse a string into **int**, while **Integer.valueOf** converts to **Integer**.